# Math operation with array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, math

Begin with selecting value from column where the value is not null.
note that the value is float.

```
$sql = "SELECT cf_user, cf_pakar FROM chevy.gejala1 WHERE cf_user != 'null' and cf_pakar != 'null'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

after that, I put it in array variable then do math operation with it.

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {
    // output data from each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $cf_user =$row["cf_user"] ;
        $cf_pakar = $row["cf_pakar"];
        $gejala = array ($cf_pakar*$cf_user);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

sample :

I have 3 value from `$cf_user` (0.2, 0.4 and 0.6) and `$cf_pakar` (1, 1 and 1),
then, `$gejala` will show 3 results.

`$cf_user*$cf_pakar` = 0.2, 0.4 and 0.6 when I echo using `foreach`.

the problem is :

what I have in `$gejala` is: (0.20.40.6) as result array.
count of `$gejala` is 1 and the value is float.

How do I separate the result? Because I have another math operation with each result letter on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the line: `$gejala = array($cf_pakar * $cf_user);` you are simply creating a new Array and thus overriding `$gejala` with each iteration into your loop. This might not provide the desired effect. Consider this option instead:

```
<?php

    // CREATE AND INITIALIZE A NEW ARRAY TO AN EMPTY VALUE.
    $gejala     = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {           
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $cf_user    = $row["cf_user"] ;
            $cf_pakar   = $row["cf_pakar"];
            // NOW PUSH THE RESULT OF YOUR MATH OPERATION, 
            // TO THE ARRAY WITH EACH ITERATION:
            $gejala[]   = round( (cf_pakar*$cf_user), 1);
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    var_dump($gejala);
```

> Or Simply:

```
<?php

    // CREATE AND INITIALIZE A NEW ARRAY TO AN EMPTY VALUE.
    $gejala     = array();

    if ($result->num_rows > 0 ) {           
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            // NOW PUSH THE RESULT OF YOUR MATH OPERATION, 
            // TO THE ARRAY WITH EACH ITERATION:
            $gejala[]   = round( ($row["cf_user"]*$row["cf_pakar"]), 1);
        }
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
    var_dump($gejala);
```

Comment: doesn't work, the result still same `$gejala[0]` result 0.20.40.6 count still 1 and `$gejala[1]` is error, I need 3 result valid for do another operation. what do you say?

Comment: I am trying use implode and explode, but it did not separate the result in array. count still 1

Comment: @RyanRizqi   Try doing a `var_dump($gejala)` to see what you get  - just like in the updated Post....

Comment: thanks for your help, I decide to put `$gejala` in temporary database so I can use the result freely.

Answer (score 0):

The way you currently have it overwrites `$gejala` with each iteration. Use the `[]` operator to append the result of your multiplication to the array instead.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $cf_user =$row["cf_user"] ;
    $cf_pakar = $row["cf_pakar"];
    $gejala[] = $cf_pakar * $cf_user;
}
```